# eBPF maps for one element. Map type and kernel/user space communication

Tags: c, kernel, ebpf

I'd create a map to store just one element (a port number) and it should be read/written both from userspace and kernelspace. 
Which map type should I use? Which size for key and value is appropriate and how can I write/read from both sides?

**_user.c**

```
/* create array map with one element */
map_fd = bpf_create_map(BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY, sizeof(key), sizeof(value), 1, 0);
...
/* update map */
ret = bpf_map_update_elem(map_fd, &key, &i, BPF_ANY);
```

**_kern.c**

How can I refer to map_fd and operate on the same map?

**EDIT:**

I could successfully create and interact with the map only in one way:
defining the map within `_kern.c` file, as follow:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") my_map = {
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
        .key_size = sizeof(uint32_t),
        .value_size = sizeof(uint32_t),
        .max_entries = 1,
};
```

That definition allows to operate directly on the map using bpf helpers like `bpf_map_lookup_elem`.

Instead within `_user.c` after loading the `_kern.o` ebpf program into the kernel through `bpf_prog_load` I used

`map_fd = bpf_object__find_map_fd_by_name(obj, "my_map");`

to retrieve the file descriptor associated with the map (I was missing this point). Once you get the file descriptor to perform, for instance, a map update you can call

```
ret = bpf_map_update_elem(map_fd, &key, &value, BPF_ANY);
```

**QUESTION:** in this case I retrieve the fd from user space using libbpf, but if I create a map from `_user.c` with `bpf_create_map` then how can I retrieve the fd from ebpf program ?

Comment: Please do _not_ change your question entirely, especially if you received answers. This makes things very difficult to follow for readers. Answer to your updated question is there is a step called ELF relocation where information for maps and in particular their file descriptors are inserted in the BPF programs. This is not trivial to do, so you usually want to let libbpf do that step; if you have created your maps beforehand, libbpf has functions to tell to reuse those maps instead of creating new ones when loading the BPF program from the ELF object file.

Comment: Thanks again, but still I can't figure out, referring to my first example, how to access to map file descriptor from the ebpf program. After the call to 
/* create array map with one element */
map_fd = bpf_create_map(BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY, sizeof(key), sizeof(value), 1, 0); I want to find a way to use map_fd in the _kern.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know you have just one element, the easiest is probably to go for an array map. In that case, you can trivially access your map entry by its index in the array: `0`.

If you were to do that, the size of the key would be the size of a 4-byte integer (`sizeof(uint32_t)`), which are always used for array indices. The size of the value would be the size you need to store your port number: very likely a `sizeof(uint16_t)`.

Then you can read/write from your BPF program by calling the relevant BPF helper functions: `bpf_map_lookup_elem()` or `bpf_map_update_elem()` (see [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html) for details). They are usually defined in `bpf_helpers.h` which is not usually installed on your system, you can find versions of it in bcc or kernel repo.

From user space, you would update the entry by using the `bpf()` system call, with its relevant commands: `BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_ELEM()` and `BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM()` (see [man page](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html)). But you don't necessarily have to re-implement the calls yourself: if you write a program, you should probably have a look at libbpf that provides wrappers. If you want to update your map from the command line, this is easy to do with `bpftool` (see [man page](https://www.mankier.com/8/bpftool-map)), something like `bpftool map <map_ref> update key 0 0 0 0 value 0x37 0x13` (update) or `bpftool map <map_ref> lookup key 0 0 0 0` (lookup).

Comment: Thanks again.
Sometimes I see u32,  can I use u32 and uint32_t interchangeably?
I have another doubt. Do eBPF helpers and libbpf functions have the same name? I mean If I want to update the map from the userspace I call bpf_map_update_elem (libbpf api) and if I want to update the map from the eBPF program in the kernel I also call bpf_map_update_elem (helper), or I'm wrong?

Also.. how can I get the file descriptor of the map in my userspace program? Is a global variable? 
Finally, why in some example bpf_create_map is used while in others there is just the definition of the map?

Comment: https://prototype-kernel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bpf/ebpf_maps.html#creating-a-map If I understood well It's the custom loader that operates on that map definition, parsing the elf file. So in my case I should use bpf_create_map from user space and then pass the returned file descriptor to the kernel. But still I can't find how to pass it.

Comment: Hard to answer all those questions in the comments :s. `u32`/`uint32_t` are essentially the same, not defined at the same place (and sometimes different meaning in kernel code, but all come down to 4-byte unsigned so don't bother too much. User space and BPF-side program update functions for maps seem to have the same names indeed, former was probably named after the latter. File descriptor you can get with libbpf either from the object used by the library (`bpf_object__find_map_by_*()`), or from the map id (`bpf_map_get_fd_by_id()`). Or it's returned by `bpf()` when you create the map.

Comment: Some examples create the maps manually with `bpf_create_map()`, some others rely on libbpf which creates them automatically when loading a BPF program from an object file. In your case, I'm not sure why you want to pass a file descriptor to the kernel. When you create a map, you call (directly or not) the `bpf()` system call, kernel creates a map, and returns a file descriptor to user space. You can later use this file descriptor to update or lookup entries from the map. The file descriptor is also used by libbpf when loading a program to tell what maps to use, but this happens under the hood.

Comment: The goal was to communicate the file descriptor to the ebpf program and permit it to work with the map because I couldn' t figure out how to refer to the map (which file descriptor is in the user space) from within the ebpf program.

Comment: On the BPF side, the `bpf_update_map_elem()` does not use a file descriptor, just a pointer to the map. You have a definition of your map in the file, so just use a pointer to that map, `&my_map`. Because of the relocation step performed by libbpf, that pointer will automatically be replaced by the relevant file descriptor when you inject the program into the kernel.

Comment: This in the case I defined the map in the _kern.c . I intended to use map_fd = bpf_create_map() within _user.c (without declaring the map in _kern.c) and use map_fd in the ebpf program.

Comment: You still need to declare the map in your program (so that program knows what kind of map it deals with), and to use `&my_map` in the same way, You don't use file descriptors in BPF programs once they're loaded. The map reuse is performed by telling libbpf to update the map in its object with info from the map you have created, see [how bpftool uses `bpf_map__reuse_fd()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/bpf/bpftool/prog.c?h=v5.2#n934) to do that (there are discussions to improve that part of the API, no consensus yet).

Comment: So, correct me If I'm wrong. Two ways: 1) mapuser_fd = bpf_create_map() in the user.c, so in the user program I can interact with the map using mapuser_fd. SEC("maps") ... within kern.c so I can use the pointer to the map and interact with the same map. I guess that the attributes (size, value, type) of the map needs to be the same in both files(?)
2) Define the map in kern.c and  interact using the pointer. Get thee fd in the user.c and interact with the map.

Comment: I don't understand why I should  use bpf_create_map if then I have to define the map also in the _kern.c file when I can just retrieves the fd . I mean I can't distinguish the different use cases between these two ways of creating and using maps.

Comment: Also I tried the second way (define the same map in the kern.c and create the same kind of map in the _user.c) but I can't interact with the fd retrieved from bpf_create_map.

Comment: You would use `bpf_create_map()` if you need your map to exist before your program is loaded, for example because you also use it for another program, or because it is essential for your use case to have the map initialised before the program is loaded. Other than this, you don't have to use it and it's simpler to let libbpf create the maps needed by the program. As for interacting with the file descriptor as you mention in your last comment, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with it. You can use it to update the map from user space, or to tell libbpf to reuse that map for a program.

Comment: I was trying just to write an example to show the use of bpf_create_map.  But I couldn't update the map created with bpf_create_map()  from the eBPF program. 
Although the example has bpf_create_map in user.c and the same  map definition in kern.c , I can't update or retrieve elements from the map. Instead If I remove bpf_create_map and I use bpf_object__find_map_fd_by_name  operations on the map work fine.

Comment: I don't know. I'd suggest asking a new question, with your code snippets (please keep the `#include`s so it's easy to compile and try to reproduce), otherwise it's tricky to debug :/